# positive martingale process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I would to like to prove that the process:

$$e^{\int_{0}^{T}\theta _{s}\,dW_{s}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\theta _{s}^2\,ds}$$
is a martingale which is positive and has a mean=1, where 
$\theta_s$ is continuous deterministic function.

Thank you

Comment: Use Ito's formula, and presumably you will get that your process can be written as an Ito stochastic integral. Then you just need to know that the expectation of the absolute value of your process is defined to know that it is a martingale.

Comment: @lan See my answer, I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 0):

Set $$X_{T}=\int_{0}^{T}\theta_{s}dW_{s}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\theta_{s}^2ds$$
then $$dX_{T}=\theta_{T}dW_{T}-\frac{1}{2}\theta_{T}^2dT$$
and using  Itô's Lemma:
$$d(e^{X_{T}})=e^{X_{T}}dX_{T}+\frac{1}{2}e^{X_T}d\langle X\rangle_{T}$$

then ?? I don't know how to continue

Comment: Then $dX=\color{red}{\theta} dW-\frac12\theta^2dt$ hence $d\langle X\rangle=\color{red}{\theta}^2dt$.

Comment: @Did 
 
How did you calculate the crochet d<X>

Comment: I used the rule that if $dY=\color{red}{a}dW+bdt$ then $d\langle Y\rangle=\color{red}{a}^2dt$.